# Getting all field names from a protocol buffer?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I want to get all the field names of a proto into a list. Is there a way to do this? I looked in the documentation and there doesn't seem to be anything for this.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Every proto class possess a [DESCRIPTOR class variable](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.message.Message-class#section-ClassVariables) that can be used to inspect the fields of corresponding protobuf messages.

Have a look at the documentation of the [Descriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.descriptor.Descriptor-class) and [FieldDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.descriptor.FieldDescriptor-class.html) classes for more details.

Here is a simple example to get the `FieldDescriptor`s of all the fields in `message` into a list:

```
res = message.DESCRIPTOR.fields
```

To get the names of the fields "exactly as they appear in the .proto file":

```
res = [field.name for field in message.DESCRIPTOR.fields]
```

or (from the comments):

```
res = message.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name.keys()
```

To get the full names of the fields "including containing scope":

```
res = [field.full_name for field in message.DESCRIPTOR.fields]
```

Comment: Does this work in a cpp implementation of protobufs too?

Comment: Yes, have a look at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message for an example. You can obtain the descriptor of a protobuf message by calling the `descriptor` class method if you know the class of the message or by calling `GetDescriptor` on the instance.

Comment: FYI `message.DESCRIPTOR.fields.keys()` does the same thing as your code.

Comment: But I don't understand why its returning on 20 fields even I have more than 20 fields in my protobuf definition.

Comment: `message.DESCRIPTOR.fields.keys()` didn't work for me but `message.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name.keys()` did.

Comment: `fields` is a list (at least today), so the `keys()` call is unneeded (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.descriptor.Descriptor-class)). Also no need to go through `fields_by_name`. Edited.

Comment: to get the actual names `[x.full_name for x in list(message.DESCRIPTOR.fields)]`

Answer (score 14):

[qfiard's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24640146/2466336) answer didn't work for me. Calling `message.DESCRIPTOR.fields.keys()` produced `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'`.

Not sure why it wouldn't work. Maybe it has something to do with how the message was defined/compiled.

The **workaround** was to do a list composition of the individual field objects and get the `name` property for each. This gave me a list of strings of all fields in this list.

```
res = [f.name for f in message.DESCRIPTOR.fields]
```

Note that this does not get you the field names within those fields recursively.

Comment: do you know how to get the field names within those fields recursively

Comment: @vks Look at the `message_type` attribute of the [FieldDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.descriptor.FieldDescriptor-class) - it returns a `Descriptor` to the message type, which you can use for getting the fields in it

Answer (score 1):

**You can easily get a list of fields as follows**

```
message_fields = [field for field in message.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

I bumped to Python 3.9 and some of these solutions broke, so I found a solution using the public interface of a message object, not using the `DESCRIPTOR` attribute.

```py
fields = [desc.name for desc, val in message.ListFields()]
```

Note however, this solution will only fetch the fields which have been set.

Doc is here: https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/message.html#google.protobuf.message.Message.ListFields