# Getting all field names from a protocol buffer in C++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Is there a way to get all the fields of a protobuff message using its descriptor, in C++?

There's a way to do that in **Python** like this:
[Getting all field names from a protocol buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639562/getting-all-field-names-from-a-protocol-buffer)

Just wondering if there's the same thing in C++. Tried to find anything on the [descriptor.h](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor), but without success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If you have a [Descriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#Descriptor), you get the number of fields using `Descriptor::field_count()`. Then, you iterate over the fields using `Descriptor::field(int index)`, which returns a [FieldDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#FieldDescriptor), where you can find the name of each field using `FieldDescriptor::name()`.