# How to determine at runtime the name of the oneof field that is set?

Tags: protobuf-net

Using `protobuf-net`, instead of iterating through each `ShouldSerialize*()`, how do I determine which `oneof` is set? I see that `ShouldSerialize*()` uses this internally `__pbn__message.Is(7)` but that private property is not accessible, and I also don't know how to get the max field number?

Trying to avoid iterating through each `ShouldSerialize*()` method because then when a new type is added, we'd need to update the iteration too.

Similar question but solved using Google's Nuget package instead:
[Getting all field names from a protocol buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639562/getting-all-field-names-from-a-protocol-buffer)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the schema parsing tools: there is an option to emit an enum and accessor that tells you exactly this. Just enable this option, and: done. How exactly to access this option depends on how you're running the tooling (at the command-line, the build-time generator, via the website, etc).

If you're writing it manually: check the `.Discriminator` accessor on the discriminated union field. To copy and paste from an answer yesterday: all the option adds is the equivalent of the following (but for your context):

```cs
public ContentOneofCase ContentCase => (ContentOneofCase)__pbn__Content.Discriminator;

public enum ContentOneofCase
{
    None = 0,
    Foo = 1,
    Bar = 2,
    Blap = 3,
}
```